# How to include external library into Android Studio and change it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to use [this MMS library](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms) in my android app. I have downloaded source and successfully built sample application included in the git.
Now I want to integrate the library into my own application that is already partially done. In the README file they say:

> To include in your gradle project:
>
> `compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT'`

**EDIT:**

I have set this to the most recent version 2.2.0 and I get an error as when you check [maven page for this lib](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.klinkerapps/android-smsmms/2.2.0) you find [this dependecy on com.klinkerapps:logger](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.klinkerapps/logger) but version 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT is not in the maven archive, latest is 1.0.2.

So the question for me now is how to add external dependency and edit its dependency so that it fits me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not download source if you are adding

`compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT'` in your gradle dependencies

just include this line in your app moudule's gradle build file and its done, if required add those permisions mentioned in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is copy compile `'compile com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT'`    into the dependencies section of your build.gradle file in the app folder

when you do that gradle will automatically download the library

it should look this

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

if you want more details check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/2102304

Comment: This does not work, as if you check http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.klinkerapps/android-smsmms/2.2.0 you see it has dependency of http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.klinkerapps/logger/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT which does not exist! how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Goto new import module add  library i.e library folder in your git project
Than goto file->Project Structure->appmodule->Dependencies->click on + ->module dependency and select your libaray module which will be added as library for you use in project